# JavaScript: Callback function vs anonymous function – Why does only one of them fires?

Tags: javascript

I noticed something weird regarding event callback functions and I am not sure what is going on.

Given the following Example:

HTML

```
<button id=btn1>Click #1</button>

<button id=btn2>Click #2</button>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
  var $button1 = $('#btn1');
  var $button2 = $('#btn2');

  $button1.on('click', function() {
    validate();
  });

  $button2.on('click', validate);

  var validate = _.debounce(function() {
    alert('validate fired');
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vo4nLhar/)

Why does Button #1 successfully triggers the `validate` function, while Button #2 does not?

My guess is that it is because the anonymous function is evaluated dynamically while the other is not, therefore `validate` isn't defined yet, but I am not sure. Could somebody please enlighten me?

Comment: Declare the `validate` debounced method before using it with `on`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those functions are anonymous.

Both of those functions are callbacks.

The second one doesn't fire because you pass the value of `validate` to `on()` **before** you assign a value to `validate` in the first place (i.e. while it is still `undefined`).

If you had used a function declaration:

```
function validate() {
   // ...
}
```

… then it would have been **hoisted** so the order wouldn't matter.

Since you are using an expression (i.e. the return value of a call to `_.debounce`) the order does matter.

Comment: You could add that using `"use strict"` could prevent this error by failing completely.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix — Strict mode wouldn't make a difference here.

Answer (score 0):

The code that is actually run after variable hoisting is this.

```
$(function() {
  var validate; // NOTICE the validate variable is hoisted.
  var $button1 = $('#btn1');
  var $button2 = $('#btn2');

  $button1.on('click', function() {
    validate();
  });

  $button2.on('click', validate); // here, validate is undefined.

  validate = _.debounce(function() {
    alert('validate fired');
  });
});
```

So by the time you put validate to `.on` handler, it is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the second call is equal to writing `$button2.on('click', undefined);` due to `var variable` being [hoisted](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-hoisting-explained--net-15092). The first callback refers to `var validate` at a time when the alerting function has been assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful how you declare your functions. There is a  difference between function declaration, function expression and how they handle **hoisting**.

With a **function declaration**, the function is always hoisted

```
   //function declaration
    function validate() {
      //do stuff
    }
```

With **function expression**, only the variable declaration gets hoisted. The variable assignement is not hoisted

```
//function expression
//unamed (anonymous function)
var validate = function() {
  //do stuff
}
```

So in your case, *validate* is undefined for button #2

Here's an article that covers the problem in depth :
https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/